# How to pass props from screen to component with stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Here is my **App.js**. It consists of 2 screens, one of which has an icon component called AddIcon

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: `Home`,
        headerTitleStyle: {
          color: '#56607b',
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: '500',
        },
        headerRight: <AddIcon />
      })
    },
    Add: {
      screen: AddScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: `Add`,
        headerTitleStyle: {
          color: '#56607b',
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: '500'
        }
      })
    },
  },
);
```

Here is **AddIcon.js**

```
const AddIcon = (props) => {
    return (
        <Icon
            name="ios-add-circle"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Add')}
        />
    );
}
```

I am trying to make it such that when the icon is pressed, it should navigate to my second screen in the stack **(AddScreen.js)**. The error I am getting now is "Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined". I figured that it is because **AddScreen.js** is the one with the navigation props, not **AddIcon.js**. Question is, how do I make it such that the icon will have the props as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the NavigationService separately

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}


export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Then in your `App.js` add ref prop to your Parent StackNavigator:

```
<RootNavigator
        ref={navigatorRef => {
          NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
        }}
/>
```

and the below code that you have to update:

```
import NavigationService from 'path-to-NavigationService.js';

<Icon
 name="ios-add-circle"
 onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate('Add')}
 />
```

You can refer official doc [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/2.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: My AddIcon component is in App.js. Tried <AddIPPTIcon navigation={this.props.navigation} /> and it didn't work. "Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined.

Comment: Why is your AddIcon in App.js file ? You should probably have it in AddScreen component.